# How to add NuGet packages to the Dockerfile build steps?

Tags: .net, docker, docker-for-windows, windows-container

I have a small .NET Framework 4.6.2 application with a few NuGet package references. On executing: `docker build -t myapp .` I receive the error: `Could not resolve this reference.` for each of the referenced NuGet packages.

I have tried:

- Adding `RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]` to restore the packages from the .csproj
- Changing the image tag to `:4.6.2`

How do I add the NuGet packages to the build proces?

Thanks for your time!

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework-build:4.7.1 as build-env

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["MessageProcessor.exe"]
```

Full error for a single reference from the Build step:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2041,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "GreenPipes, Version=1.2.1.98, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b800c4cfcdeea87b, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\app\MessageProcessor.csproj]
```

Comment: in my case i only have ```RUN dotnet  restore``` and it works. are you in the right folder when you run ```COPY . .``` ? What was your output from dotnet restore

Comment: Edited the COPY line. When I add `RUN dotnet restore` I get the output: `Restore:
  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
Done Building Project "C:\app\MessageProcessor.csproj" (Restore target(s)).`

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but is not this .NET core and not full .NET framework and hence dotnet is not used to build the projects?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian The app is based on a .NET Framework 4.6.2 based project. I wish using .NET Core was an option...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figured it out.

MSBuild (`RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]`) doesn't restore the NuGet packages for some reasons explained [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4821). So I started playing around with nuget.exe commands and that worked eventually.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework-build:4.7.1 as build-env

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN nuget.exe restore MessageProcessor.csproj -SolutionDirectory ../ -Verbosity normal
RUN MSBuild.exe MessageProcessor.csproj /t:build /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=./out

FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["MessageProcessor.exe"]
```

This leaves me a nice clean and shiny .NET Framework 4.6.2 Docker container.

Comment: For those who stumbled upon the answer. `dotnet restore` is CLI utility for `.NET Core`, not `.NET Framework` that's why you need to use `.NET Framework` utilities like `nuget.exe` or `MSBuild.exe`